# Why doesn't this JsFiddle load on my page? (using Brackets)

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm using Brackets. 
For the first time, I'm trying to implement a script.
So I want to use this person's script: 
https://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/m1ezs70o/

I pasted the Javascript portion inside the `<head>` tag

```
var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
            "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
        },
        "Texas": {
            "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
            "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
        }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": {
            "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
            "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
        }
    }
}


window.onload = function () {

    //Get html elements
    var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"); 
    var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");

    //Load countries
    for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
        countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
    }

    //County Changed
    countySel.onchange = function () {

         stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done

         for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
             stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
         }
    }

    //State Changed
    stateSel.onchange = function () {        

         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done

         for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
             citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
         }
    }

    //City Changed
    citySel.onchange = function () {
        zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
            return; // done

        var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
            zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

I pasted the HTML portion inside the `<body>` tag

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br>

    <select id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <select id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="zipSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And yet when the page loads, when I click on the dropdown boxes, none of the options from the Javascript code show up.

Is there some additional step I'm missing here? First time trying with scripts.

Comment: It works by order, you need to select a country, then state, then city then zipcode.

Comment: when I try to put this in my website code, I am not able to select a country. it is as if the page is not detecting the script code.

Comment: Is your website live or local?

Comment: It is local. Using Brackets Live Preview

Comment: Can you try to check and see if the code is executing? Put somewhere inside of the code alert("works") and see if it triggers it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the alert does show up. So I have no idea why the rest of the code doesn't work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176439/discussion-between-grandiq-and-matthew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved by placing the `<script>` at the end of body. Seemed like it was interfering with other possible loads.

```js
var countryStateInfo = {
 "USA": {
  "California": {
   "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
   "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
  },
  "Texas": {
   "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
   "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
  }
 },
 "India": {
  "Assam": {
   "Dispur": ["781005"],
   "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
  },
  "Gujarat": {
   "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
   "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
  }
 }
}


window.onload = function () {
 
 //Get html elements
 var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
 var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"); 
 var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
 var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");
 
 //Load countries
 for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
  countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
 }
 
 //County Changed
 countySel.onchange = function () {
   
   stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
   citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
   zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
   
   if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
    return; // done
   
   for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
    stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
   }
 }
 
 //State Changed
 stateSel.onchange = function () {   
   
   citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
   zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
   
   if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
    return; // done
   
   for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
    citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
   }
 }
 
 //City Changed
 citySel.onchange = function () {
  zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
  
  if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
   return; // done
  
  var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
  for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
   zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
  }
 } 
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br>
  
    <select id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <select id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="zipSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
    </select>
</form>

<p>First select a country => state => city => zipcode</p>
```

Comment: when I try to put this in my website code, I am not able to select a country. it is as if the page is not detecting the script code.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what's wrong in the original code and what you changed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I also faces same issue. I created another fiddle with same Data and surprisingly it wasn't loading.

I also check if there is any additional library added. But no library was attached.

Finally in jsfiddle => js tab, there is option to select load type and it was `on load`  I changed it to `bottom of Head` and it worked.

So if we put script inside head section or on top. JS will not work. It has to be at bottom. after HTMl loads.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofyts3pg/8/)